# How to reset padding so lists padding are shown correctly?

Tags: css

I have `body * { padding: 0; }`. This removes all padding from list. Without removing the CSS, what can I add that can bring back padding for lists ?

Comment: When you say list do you mean `ul` and `ol`? What do you mean by "without removing the CSS"? What have you tried to add the padding back?

Comment: I am using `ul` but it should work the same for `ol` as well. And for that, I meant, without removing `body * { padding: 0; }` from the CSS file

Comment: Can you show us what you wrote? Is it not working as you expected? Edit your question and put your code into a code snippet so we can have a working example here.

Comment: I don't know what you mean ? I just have a html with some ul and list, and for CSS I have `body * { padding: 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `padding` for list elements is `40px`.

Note that setting a `padding` on list elements also removes their bullet, so you'll also probably want to add this back in with `list-style-position: inside`. This offsets the bullet a little bit, so you may want to go with `30px` of `padding` instead.

```css
body * {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0 30px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<p>No padding</p>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

However, a better option would be to simply not set padding on the list elements in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Add your own back in. You have to make it as "specific" are the reset itself.

```
body ul, body ol { padding: (your value) }
```

See: http://cssspecificity.com/

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally I'd question the approach of using `body * { padding: 0; }` since it's far too broad a rule to reasonably apply to a well-structured layout, but in your case, you could do a couple things.

```
body ul, body ol { padding: 15px; }
```

The above will add padding to the list wrapper, but you may also want to cover the listitems as well.

```
body li { padding: 15px; }
```

Both of the above options would need to come after your existing removal of the padding.

The final alternative would be to use a not selector *instead* of your `body *` selector.

```
body :not(li) { padding: 0; }
```

Or, to protect ul, ol, and li:

```
body :not(li):not(ul):not(ol) { padding: 0; }
```